# Работа с uDMX через uDMX.dll

Tags: c#

Первый вопрос: на сайте разработчика DLL есть API, но часть функций в нем не работает (а именно connected()) поэтому вопрос, как узнать что устройство подключено?

Второй вопрос: при использовании ChannelSet() подключенное устройство не реагирует, можете дать пример рабочего кода или объяснение как работает данный запрос?

Upd. Есть DMX кабель для подключения устройств и сайт разработчика с библиотекой для работы с ним На сайте есть API, но при запросе некоторых функций выдает ошибку NoEntryPoint (первый вопрос), мне надо либо узнать каким-либо образом точное имя функции для запросов Так-же при запросе функции из второго вопроса устройство не реагирует, но понять причину нельзя, так как документации по этому вопросу на сайте нет. Нужен способ узнать почему ничего не происходит, это ошибка DLL, кабеля или моего кривого кода

Comment: Посмотрите на свой вопрос глазами человека, который ничего не знает о контексте, к котором Вы находитесь.

Comment: Есть DMX кабель для подключения устройств и сайт разработчика с библиотекой для работы с ним

На сайте есть API, но при запросе некоторых функций выдает ошибку NoEntryPoint (первый вопрос), мне надо либо узнать каким-либо образом точное имя функции для запросов

Так-же при запросе функции из второго вопроса устройство не реагирует, но понять причину нельзя, так как документации по этому вопросу на сайте нет. Нужен способ узнать почему ничего не происходит, это ошибка DLL, кабеля или моего кривого кода

Comment: Вот это все должно быть не в комментариях, а в тексте вопроса, чтобы человек со стороны без напряжения и лишних телодвижений в Интернете смог понять Вашу проблему. Подробности, если они по делу, не бывают лишними.

Comment: Посмотреть на сайте разработчика демку по работе с их длл, с нее и начните, а не с собственного кода. Вполне вероятно что она может и не работать :) это не редкость. Так же изучите хеадер к ней, и порядок инициализации, хотя бы на основании хеадера от этой-же длл. Так же возможно что это COM dll - ее надо регистрировать в системе.

Comment: Up, по udmx есть разумный форум, где его активно используют, рекомендую туда с этим вопросом https://svetovik.info/topic/1754-kak-nastroit-udmx-c-progoy-sunlite/?do=findComment&comment=9294

Comment: DLL на системе зарегистрирована (по крайней мере на машине где проходят тесты), так как другие программы работают, на сайте есть пример на Visual Basic, но он уже собран

А на световике работают с физической стороной вопроса, а не программной, но за ссылку благодарю

Comment: Пример на визуальном бейсике декомпилируется путем применения il дизассемблера https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler